# How can I redirect to login page in spring service class?

Tags: java, spring-security

Here I am writing spring security application. In UserDetailsService implementation class I want to redirect to login page.I alredy have HttpServletRequest in this class. Here i my code.

```
if (alredyLogedIn == true) {

                UserAudit dbUserAudit = appServiceManager.getUserAudit(userId);

                System.out.println(dbUserAudit.getLoginstarttime());

                String userAgent = (request).getHeader("User-Agent");
                UserAudit userAudit = new UserAudit();
                userAudit.setUserid(userId);
                userAudit.setLoginstarttime(dbUserAudit.getLoginstarttime());
                userAudit.setLogoutdatetime(sqlTimestamp);
                userAudit.setLoginstatus("Logout");


                int result = appServiceManager.updateUserAudit(userAudit);

                if (result != 0) {

                    request.getSession().invalidate();

                }
                 return "loginform"; 

            }
```

If the user alredy login, then I want to send him to login page.

Answer (score 0):

I Redirected the login page regularly with `response.sendRedirect("loginform");`. Nothing morethan this.